# ASP:Fileupload or AjaxFileUpload with AllowMultiple tag not working in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I tried looking for answers but I couldn't find the especific one I have.

I have an application running on .net 4.5 for the sole reason that I needed a FileUpload 'AllowMultiple' option. It works when I test it on my computer but it is not the case when I publish it to my server. The server is running 2012 R2 (natively includes 4.5). Is there something I need to configure for it to work, an add-on or patch or something? IE11 is the client in both environments (but it also doesn't work with Chrome or FF)

```
<asp:FileUpload class="textbox" ID="upload" runat="server" Width="378px" AllowMultiple="True" />
```

I tried AjaxFileupload and it is not working for multiple files either. This is only on the server.

I would greatly appreciate any insight.

EDIT: Adding. I have tried installing 4.5.1 Multi Targeting Pack and changed my application tu run on 4.5.1. In dispair I also changed assemblies literally copying them to the 4.0 directory. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: When I say it runs on test it's when you run a test from VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what solved it

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/2004302.aspx?UploadFile+Control+Not+Allowing+Multiple+File+Selection+in+IE+11